# When allowing users to mute notifications in an app, what time duration options are most useful?

Tags: usability, user-expectation, mobile-application, user-centered-design, chat

How does screenshot posted below make a difference by allowing to mute chats for 8 hours, 1 week, and 1 year and leaving some of the obvious usability cases like 1 month?

What time-duration options are most useful?

[image: ios WhatsApp mute mode usability]
[image: android WhatsApp mute mode usability]

Comment: We can only speculate. You'll have to contact WhatsApp directly to find the answer for this.

Comment: 8 hours make sense because you're busy with some work and don't want to be disturbed. One week makes sense because say you're out vacationing or on a business trip, you'd prefer if notifications were not bothering you constantly. One year was introduced (remember that mute began with being available for only groups and later extended to personal chat) incase you had no interest in the group notifications but couldn't not be a part of it (insert: family groups, lol?). One month might complete the set but there needs to be a purpose the option serves. One month doesn't serve any in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion based, but I think it could be re-worded to be more general purpose, like: "When allowing users to mute notifications in an app, what time duration options are most useful?"